# arm-none-eabi-gcc very slow but time report say that is fast on windows

Tags: gcc, arm

I m using gcc for arm on windows but it is very slow :
compiled file:

```
#include "stdint.h"
int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
     // code
     return 0; // Indicates that everything went well.
}
```

Command used:

```
bash-3.1$ time C\:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GNU\ Tools\ ARM\ Embedded/5.4\ 2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -c -ftime-report main.c
```

result:

```
bash-3.1$ time C\:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GNU\ Tools\ ARM\ Embedded/5.4\ 2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -c -ftime-report main.c

    Execution times (seconds)
     phase setup             :   0.01 (52%) usr    1538 kB (90%) ggc
     phase parsing           :   0.01 (26%) usr     127 kB ( 7%) ggc
     TOTAL                 :   0.02              1707 kB

    real    0m0.795s
    user    0m0.000s
    sys     0m0.015s
```

and with missing file:

```
bash-3.1$ time C\:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GNU\ Tools\ ARM\ Embedded/5.4\ 2016q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -c -ftime-report main.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: main.c: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

real    0m0.123s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

So I don't understant why gcc is so slow

Ps : host is a Intel i7 with ssd and 8Go of RAM

Answer (score 0):

A trick I use to speed up GCC (MinGW-w64 build from http://winlibs.com/ in my case) and MSYS2 shell is to use a RAM-drive.

I use ImDisk from: http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk

To set up a RAM drive of 4G (adjust this to a proper value for your system) I run (in an elevated prompt):

```
imdisk -a -t vm -s 4G -m R: -p "/FS:NTFS /V:RAMDisk /Q /Y" -o rem
MKDIR R:\TEMP
ECHO Y|CACLS R:\ /G Everyone:F /T /C
```

The last line is to set the NTFS permissions as simple as possible so no time is wasted there.

Then (as your normal user before compiling) you need to point the `TEMP` environment variable to the RAM-drive.

In a Command Prompt (if you also run your compiler in the same Command Prompt) you can do this with:

```
SET TEMP=R:\TEMP
```

In your bash shell it probably is something like this:

```
export TMP=R\:/TEMP
export TEMP=R\:/TEMP
```

To speed things up even more I also build any software from source on the same RAM-drive.

But even if your source is on disk (HDD or SSD) the build process compiler will be faster as it creates (and deletes) files regularly in the temporary folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know what's slow, profile it. In a similar situation, years ago, I used [StraceNT](https://chocolatey.org/packages/StraceNT). I don't remember the exact command line.

In my case, which was with Cygwin tools, the timings showed that what was slow about Cygwin programs was file access, and the trace showed that the (company-mandated) antivirus hooked into every system call.

Compiling a complex program with intensive optimization may be CPU-bound, but compiling hello world without optimization is completely IO-bound. Whatever the reason for the slowness, it's in the file access.

A different Windows build of the same compiler may or may not be faster. A Linux build running in a virtual machine is likely to be faster if you have enough RAM that your system doesn't start to swap (of course a native Linux would be faster).

Using a RAM disk may speed up large builds (although only if the OS does a mediocre job at managing the disk cache). But if the problem is that file I/O system calls are slow, and not that the filesystem I/O is slow, that won't help.